# Data matching in R

Tags: r, regex, match

I have two dataframes with the same length (1000) and width (200). In both dataframes, each row is a person. In one dataframe, each column is a binary item score (i.e. 0 or 1). In the other dataframe, each column is the item label. Here is it:

Dataframe 1:

```
item1 item2 item3
0     1     1
1     0     0
1     1     1
```

Dataframe 2:

```
item1   item2   item3
C2HSD   WW11S3  EI22S
WW11S3  2JDDS   TT6SQ1
EI22S   TT6SQ1  331ID
```

What I want is a combined and matched dataframe like this:

```
C2HSD  WW11S3 EI22S 2JDDS TT6SQ1 331ID
0      1      1     NA    NA     NA
NA     1      NA    0     0      NA
NA     NA     1     NA    1      1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `melt` the two datasets to 'long' format', do a `left_join`, and later `spread` it to 'wide' format after removing the 'Var2'

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)
d1 <- melt(as.matrix(df1))
d2 <- melt(as.matrix(df2))
left_join(d2, d1, by = c("Var1", "Var2")) %>% 
      select(-Var2) %>% 
      spread(value.x, value.y) %>%
      select(-Var1)
#   2JDDS 331ID C2HSD EI22S TT6SQ WW11S
#1    NA    NA     0     1    NA     1
#2     0    NA    NA    NA     0     1
#3    NA     1    NA     1     1    NA
```

---

A `base R` option would be to `replace` the corresponding column values of 'df2' with NA where the 'df1' values are 0 using `Map`, then `stack` it to 'data.frame', `transform` the 'values' column to `factor` and get the frequency with `table`

```
un1 <- unique(unlist(df2))
table(transform(stack(Map(function(x,y) replace(y, !x, NA), 
  df1, df2))[2:1], values = factor(values, levels = un1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

An attempt in base R uses `mapply` and `match` as follows. The code below uses `match` to return a vector with NAs where a column of dat2 does not have any of the variables and the respective value of dat1 where there is a match in dat2. For the desired output structure, the dat1 data.frame has to be transposed (`data.frame(t(dat1))`).

```
# get the vector of unique names in dat2
vars <- unique(unlist(dat2))
mapply(function(x, y, vars) x[match(vars, y)],
       data.frame(t(dat1)), dat2, MoreArgs=list(vars=vars))
     X1 X2 X3
[1,]  0 NA NA
[2,]  1  1 NA
[3,]  1 NA  1
[4,] NA  0 NA
[5,] NA  0  1
[6,] NA NA  1
```

to return a data.frame with the named variables, wrap this in `t`, `data.frame`, and `setNames`.

```
setNames(data.frame(t(mapply(function(x, y, vars) x[match(vars, y)],
                             data.frame(t(dat1)), dat2, MoreArgs=list(vars=vars)))), vars)

   C2HSD WW11S3 EI22S 2JDDS TT6SQ1 331ID
X1     0      1     1    NA     NA    NA
X2    NA      1    NA     0      0    NA
X3    NA     NA     1    NA      1     1
```

The data below has dat2 as character vectors rather than factors. This is the preferable storage type for this sort of operation.

**data**

```
dat1 <- 
structure(list(item1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), item2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), 
    item3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("item1", "item2", "item3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
dat2 <- 
structure(list(item1 = c("C2HSD", "WW11S3", "EI22S"), item2 = c("WW11S3", 
"2JDDS", "TT6SQ1"), item3 = c("EI22S", "TT6SQ1", "331ID")), .Names = c("item1", 
"item2", "item3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```